# how to use less with bootstrap?

Tags: css, less

there are 3 files, less.js, style.less and style.css. I so far don't understand what the less.js do. Do I need to include it in somewhere? and for style.less, I know I should write less in it and it compile to my style.css, but should I included it in my index.html?

I don't understand the guide in less.org.

Comment: `less.js` just lets you directly load the `.less` files as stylesheets. In production, you compile the `.less` files into `.css` files and load those instead.

Comment: less.js to be included in index.html head?

Comment: Look at the website: http://lesscss.org/#usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you don't need to use less in order to use Twitter Bootstrap. The idea behind less to have smaller style sheet files. And Being that Bootstraps css is so large, less helps mitigate that issue. Now about the files you mentioned.

Browsers don't understand `*.less` files. `less.js`, in this context, serves as the "compiler"
 for the `*.less` files

**Start from the website:**

Link your .less stylesheets with the rel set to “stylesheet/less”:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

Then download less.js from the top of the page, and include it in the  element of your page, like so:

```
 <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**End from the website**

They mention compiling the `*.less` into a proper css. What they should have elaborated somewhere on the site is "Why compile less?"

- Like all code, less will require debugging
- Running it through a command line compiler can find errors that `less.js` can't
- `less.js` is an additional file and processing load that is put on the browser. Hence compiling `*.less` into `*.css` can make for a faster browsing experience

The Bootstrap gives you the option of choosing either css or less